# Can I use the RaspberryPi to receive the GameCube remote's RF signals?

Tags: control, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have an old gamecube that doesn't work and I want to gut it and fill it with Arduino boards and/or Raspberry Pi if necessary.  I want the project to eventually have some kind of AI aspect, but I'm also toying with the idea of using a [wireless GameCube remote and wavebird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WaveBird_Wireless_Controller) to issue commands at the push of a button.

I guess this would be mostly good for testing purposes, but I'm mostly curious if and how I would go about making my RaspberryPi understand Gamecube remote input.  Furthermore, would this kind of idea be feasible?

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert the GameCube interface to be a USB game controller, this should go fairly smoothly.  I used to buy used USB Xbox and Playstation2 controllers to control our underwater vehicles, and use [Python's pygame library for joystick support](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) to read the input from it.

[image: joysticking in the ocean]
[image: joysticking with live video]

Pygame makes it pretty easy.  For example, [this script to show joystick position](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Joystick_position#Python).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely feasible. I realize this won't be a "complete" answer according to the rules here, but either way here's some links to point you in the (hopefully) right direction:

[Rather complete tutorial on making a GameCube controller to USB converter](http://www.raphnet.net/electronique/gc_n64_usb/index_en.php)

[The same adapter ready to go for $30CAD](http://www.raphnet-tech.com/products/gc_n64_usb_adapters/index.php)

[Short forum discussion about GameCube serial interface](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showthread.php?t=41524)